# How to find the operating system drive

Tags: vb6

How can I detect the drive on which the operating system is installed using VB6?

```
Private Sub GetSystemDrive()
    ' What to write here?
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the drive on which the OS is installed?
Also, why do you need it? To access the Windows directory and other such System Folders, you can use %windir%, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using API calls is slightly more reliable than accessing environment

```
Private Declare Function GetWindowsDirectory Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetWindowsDirectoryA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long

Private Function GetSystemDrive() As String
    GetSystemDrive = Space(1000)
    Call GetWindowsDirectory(GetSystemDrive, Len(GetSystemDrive))
    GetSystemDrive = Left$(GetSystemDrive, 2)
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Debug.Print GetSystemDrive
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my dear... It worked very very fine. God Bless You.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way is to use the environment variable `%SystemDrive%`. You can access environment variables using `Environ`, e.g. `Environ("SystemDrive")`.

If you are on a Win9x OS, you can use `%WinDir%` and just extract the drive portion, e.g. `Left(Environ("WinDir"), 2)`.

Comment: +1 This method is a little eaiser than the API calls, and should be ok as long as there is no one messing around with the Environment Variables.  In addition, if you type "Set" into the windows command prompt it will give you a list of all the Environ Variables that you can query : )

Comment: FYI, `%SystemDrive%` is only available on Win NT derivatives.